# Solder SMD on through hole

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, pcb-assembly, through-hole

Can I just solder an SMD part directly on the through holes of the PCB?

The pitch of SMD matches the pitch of the through holes.

Comment: I have done this many times. I have salvaged many boards that did not have high bypass capacitor on the regulator input. They fit nicely between the pads and look clean when finished.

Comment: What is the part? Is it high power, or does it require cooling?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For DIY project, no problem.

If you manufactured a large quantity then you'd have to care about having a low number of defects which means taking care of all the details. But for one-off DIY projects, yolo.

Unless there's something you're not saying, like the SMD part is a power transistor or LDO that needs a copper plane for heat sinking, stuff like that.